# regular exprssion for atleast and at most characters

Tags: regex

I am new in regular expression. I can't do what want. I have made the regular expression given below

```
var emailx= /^([a-zA-Z_.]+@[a-z]+[.]+[a-zA-Z]+)$/;
```

But in the end I want at least 3 character and at most 5 character after the dot sign`([.])`.

Can you please help me how to do that.

Thank you.

Comment: is there any particular reason you are blacklisting a lot of valid email formats?

Comment: Do you know that TLD may have much more than 5 character length and also country code are 2 character long? Have a look at http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most Regex flavors (you don't say which you are using) you can use a `{min,max}` quantifier. For example:

```
[a-zA-Z]{3,5}
```

If you happen to be using a flavor without this, then you can do:

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]?[a-zA-Z]?
```

Also, if you want exactly one dot, you should use `\.`, not `[.]+` which is "one or more dots". And you can make this case-insensitive to simplify:

```
var emailx = /^([a-z_.]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]{3,5})$/i;
```

Finally, note that your regex will discard many, many legal email addresses. Like my `!@phrogz.net`, for example. Here's a more robust one (that still is not good enough, IMHO):
http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: well.. in general I agree with the approach in that link, but with all these new TLDs becoming available, it's going to have to be modified soon!

Answer (score 0):

You can use {MIN_OCCURANCE, MAX_OCCURANCE} in your regex.

```
Like {3,5}
```